# Need help with this counting problem (related to finite fields).

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

If $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a field with $q$ elements, then ${\mathbb{F}_q^r}^\times$ is the set of all non-zero vectors over (or $r$-tuples with entries from) $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Then $|{\mathbb{F}_q^r}|= |\mathbb{F}_q \times \cdots \times \mathbb{F}_q| = q^r$, so that $|{\mathbb{F}_q^r}^\times|=q^r - 1$.

Given a non-zero vector $v \in \mathbb{F}_q^r$, we have a set of $q-1$ non-zero scalar multiples of $v$ - namely $\{\alpha v: 0\not= \alpha \in \mathbb{F}_q\}$.

Question: How are there in all $n=(q^r - 1)/(q-1)$ pairwise disjoint sets of this kind that form a partition of ${\mathbb{F}_q^r}^\times$?

Comment: That follows immediately from the fact that any two such sets are identical or disjoint.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So said our teacher in class too, but I'm having a hard time seeing this for some reason. If possible, can you explain this in a little more detail, please?

Comment: Which? The fact that any two are identical or disjoint, or the fact that the result follows from this?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That the result follows...

Comment: Okay; I’ve tried to fill out the explanation in the answer that I just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the family of all sets of the given form. $\mathscr{F}$ is a pairwise disjoint family of subsets of ${\Bbb F_q^r}^\times$. Now $|{\Bbb F_q^r}^\times|=q^r-1$, and $|F|=q-1$ for each $F\in\mathscr{F}$, so

$$|\mathscr{F}|\le\frac{q^r-1}{q-1}\::$$

there simply isn’t room for any more pairwise disjoint sets of size $q-1$ in ${\Bbb F_q^r}^\times$. On the other hand, each $v\in{\Bbb F_q^r}^\times$ belongs to some member of $\mathscr{F}$, namely, $\{\alpha v:\alpha\in\Bbb F_q^\times\}$, so $\bigcup\mathscr{F}={\Bbb F_q^r}^\times$. That is, the members of $\mathscr{F}$ completely fill up ${\Bbb F_q^r}^\times$, with no vectors left over, so

$$|\mathscr{F}|=\frac{q^r-1}{q-1}\:.$$